# Polymorphic behavior not being implemented

Tags: java

The last two lines of this code illustrate the problem: the compiler works when I use the reference to the object, but not when I assign the reference to an array element. The rest of the code is in the same package in separate files. BioStudent and ChemStudent are separate classes, as well as Student.

```
package pkgPoly;

public class Poly {
   public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Student[] stud = new Student[3];

        // create a biology student
        BioStudent s1 = new BioStudent("Tom");

        // create a chemistry student
        ChemStudent s2 = new ChemStudent("Dick");

        // fill the student body with studs
        stud[0] = s1;
        stud[1] = s2;


        // compiler complains that it can't find symbol getMajor on next line
        System.out.println("major: " + stud[0].getMajor() ); // doesn't compile; 

        System.out.println("major: " + s0.getMajor() );   // works: compiles and runs correctly
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? And possibly the code for `Student`.

Comment: compiler complains that it can't find symbol getMajor on next line - he wrote in the comment

Comment: The error message is "source\pkgPoly\Poly.java:50: error: cannot find symbol   symbol: method getMajor()  location: class Student

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Student`? My guess would be that `getMajor` is defined on `BioStudent` and `ChemStudent`, but not on `Student` (e.g. as an abstract method).

Comment: I really doubt your last line works. `S0` is nowhere defined. Two reference variables that you have are `S1` and `S2`.

Comment: Also, where's the variable declaration for `s0`?

Comment: Polymorphism in Java works. Read the error message and confer with the types in question.

Comment: OK let's start over. I tried to keep the listing here simple but I did not replace the variable names in the lines above. The actual listing is

Comment: see above with changes

Comment: @GarrettA.Hughes By `s0.getMajor()` you mean `s1.getMajor()`? Also since you are using array of `Student` type and you can't use `stud[0].getMajor()` it seems that this method is not defined in `Student` class.

Comment: @GarrettA.Hughes A word of advice `Always provide minimal but sufficient code that is suitable for your question` How is anyone going to help you when half of the time they are getting a clarification on what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of missing info, such as what is s0, or if BioStudent and ChemStudent extend Student, however **I'll just assume** all of this is true and s0 is either a BioStudent or ChemStudent.

If so, I'm not entirely sure about the proper terminology, but when you use a reference variable of the parent type and point it to a Child object, you can only access the child methods if these override the parent methods.

In other words, you need to have the getMajor() method defined in your parent class Student, then overriden in your child class BioStudent and/or ChemStudent.

Comment: I was missing the getMajor() method in the Student class - thanks Cristobal!!

Answer (score 1):

stud is an object of class Student.

I am assuming few things -

- BioStudent and ChemStudent extends Student class.
- BioStudent has a method getMajor()
- Student Class does not!

That is the reason stud[0].getMajor() is giving you a compile time error.

You have to typecast it to the subclass of Student.

```
System.out.println("major: " + ((BioStudent) stud[0]).getMajor() );
```

Comment: Though it would be better to define `getMajor()` in `Student`, rather than having to cast to a subclass every time you wanted to call the method — to which subclass should which variable be cast?

Comment: I was missing the getMajor() method in the Student class  - thanks ajc

Comment: I don't need the cast if the method is overridden in the subclass. I am just playing with this stuff as it is all new to me - thanks again

Answer (score 1):

According to the information given I am assuming couple of things.

- Student is a super class
- BioStudent and ChemStudent extends Student
- stud[0] = s1
- stud[1] = s2

The error that you are getting is because Student class doesnt have `getMajor()` but the BioStudent and ChemStudent has that method.

You have created a Student array. For the compiler `stud[0]` is Student class, not the BioStudent nor ChemStudent. Only during the runtime jre would know that stud[0] has BioStudent and stud[1] has ChemStudent. That is why you are getting the compilation error.

- **Solution 1:**

  Either add `getMajor()` method to Student class and the other 2 class overrides it.

OR

- **Solution 2:**

  Typecast by adding this to your print statement `(BioStudent stud[0]).getMajor()` - which explicitly means this is BioStudent object and the compiler would know BioStudent has `getMajor()`.